# Setting SASS variables for Vuetify 3 components

Tags: webpack, vuetify.js, webpack-5, vuetifyjs3

I following the guide from the official [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#variable-api), using webpack@5.89.0 and webpack-plugin-vuetify@2.0.1

My configuration:

resources/vuetify/settings.scss

```
@forward "vuetify/settings" with (
    $color-pack: true,
    $utilities: false,
    $button-height: 106px,
);
```

plugins/vuetify.js

```
import 'vuetify/styles';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
export default createVuetify()
```

But I get an error

```
SassError: SassError: Module loop: this module is already being loaded.
  ┌──> vuetify/settings.scss
1 │ ┌ @forward "vuetify/settings" with (
2 │ │     $color-pack: true,
3 │ │     $utilities: false,
4 │ │     $button-height: 106px,
5 │ │ );
  │ └─^ new load
  ╵
  ┌──> node_modules/.cache/vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass
1 │   @use "/Users/roman_dev/work/reseller/resources/vuetify/settings.scss"
  │   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ original load
  ╵
  vuetify/settings.scss 1:1                             @use
  node_modules/.cache/vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass 1:1  root stylesheet
    at Object.loader (/Users/roman_dev/work/reseller/resources/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:69:14)
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass 4:14-109
 @ ./common/vue/plugins/vuetify.js 1:0-24
 @ ./manager/ui/src/js/app.js 12:0-60 23:8-15
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Trying to connect

resources/vuetify/settings.scss

```
@forward "vuetify" with (
    $color-pack: true,
    $utilities: false,
    $button-height: 106px,
);
```

in this case the error looks different

```
SassError: SassError: This variable was not declared with !default in the @used module.
  ╷
4 │     $button-height: 106px,
  │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```

Comment: The first one will probably work if you name it something other than vuetify/settings.scss